# Only 'pwd.db' gets updated, the other 2 are ignored

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import os

x = (str(os.getcwd())[0:12])
password = (x + '\\dbs\\pwd.db')
used = (x + '\\dbs\\pwd_used.db')
wallet = (x + '\\dbs\\wlt.db')

con = sqlite3.connect(password)
valuta = int(0)
to_check = str(input("Geef de verkregen code: "))

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pwd")
    try:
        while True:
            row = cur.fetchone()
            if row[0] == to_check:
                valuta = int(row[1])
                print("Je hebt een juiste code ingevoerd")
                print(f"En je heb hiermee {valuta} coins verdiend.")
                invoer1 = str(row[0])
                invoer2 = row[1]
                cur.execute("DELETE from pwd where code = ?", (invoer1, ))
                con = sqlite3.connect(used)
                with con:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur.execute("insert into pwd_used ('code', 'value') VALUES (?, ?)", (invoer1, invoer2))
                    con = sqlite3.connect(wallet)
                    with con:
                        cur = con.cursor()
                        cur.execute("SELECT cash FROM wlt where onlyone=1")
                        huidige_waarde = cur.fetchone()
                        for cash in huidige_waarde:
                            cash = cash + valuta
                            onlyone = int(1)
                            cur.execute("UPDATE cash SET cash=? WHERE onlyone=1", (cash))
                            con.commit()
            else:
                continue
    except:
        print(" ")
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The names are right, triple checked (DBs, tables and fields)
The the location is right.

I'm trying to create:

- 1 database with passwords
- 1 database with used passwords
- 1 database that keeps a total sum of cash

Comment: You're not committing all your changes, only the last one.

Comment: Don't reuse the variables `con` and `cur`. Open all 3 connections at the start, using different variables for each connection and its corresponding cursor.

Comment: Since you reuse the variable `cur`, when the `while` loop repeats, `cur.fetchone()` tries to use the cursor from `allet` instead of the cursor that was fetching from the `pwd` query.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar, I've got it working :)